Charts of Lambda Function usage in AWS
I have multiple Serverless PHP applications deployed at AWS via Vapor for Laravel.
The Lambda bill is high since a few months. I wanna know which Lambda are causing the higher usage. But I can't find a simple/useful way to sort out the usage per Lambda function.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912163/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-cost-of-a-single-lambda-function
